# Presto SQL group by COL1 and concat COL2 values

Tags: sql, hive, presto

Say I have this

```
col_1 | col_2
------------
1    |    a    
1    |    b    
1    |    c    
2    |    d    
2    |    e
```

I want result like this

```
col_1 | col_2_concat
-------------------
1     |     a,b,c
2     |     d,e
```

something like this I would guess:

```
select
    col_1,
    join_by_comma(col2)
from tbl
group by col_1
```

Comment: You are looking for `LISTAGG()` or `GROUP_CONCAT()` that typically exist in relational databases. See example at https://ahana.io/answers/presto-equivalent-of-mysql-group_concat/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        'a' AS c,
        'b' AS c2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'a',
        'b2'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'a2',
        'b3'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'a2',
        'b4'
)
SELECT
    c,
    ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(c2), ',') as c2
FROM x
GROUP BY
    c
```

Comment: Personally I found `values` convenient for test data generation - `with x(c,c2) as (values ('a','b'), ('a1','b1'))`